# Copy specific lines in txt file into one new txt file

Tags: python

I’m working with the python.

I have 1 .txt file:

```
Data = 10,
Time taken = 2s,
Architecture = Microcontroller,
Speed = 1s,
Device = STC12C,
```

I want to copy only into new txt file :

```
Architecture = Microcontroller,
Device = STC12C,
```

Comment: Do you mean selecting line 3 and line 5? Or selecting "Architecture" and "Device"?

Comment: Selecting the line 3 and line 5, Sir

Comment: Use `readlines` to get a list of lines, and select index 2 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

```
# filepath is the path of the file you are reading
# for example filepath = r"C:\Users\joe\folder\txt_file.txt"
f = open(filepath, "r")
Lines=f.readlines() #here you have a list of all the lines
new_text = Lines[2] + Lines[4]
```

If you print new_text you get :

```
>>> 
Architecture = Microcontroller,
Device = STC12C,
```

Which is what we want. Now you save it into a new file.

```
# filepath if the path of the file you want to create 
# for example filepath = r"C:\Users\joe\folder\new_txt_file.txt"
text_file = open(newfilepath, "w")
 
#write string to file
text_file.write(new_text)
 
#close file
text_file.close()

f.close() # I forgot to close the first file
```

##### Edit :  By using `with open`  you won't need to close the files, as mentioned by @[CrazyChucky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12975140/crazychucky).

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    Lines=f.readlines()
new_text = Lines[2] + Lines[4]

with open(newfilepath, 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_text)
```

Comment: You never closed the first file. (Using the `with open()` syntax means you don't have to remember to.)